# Reference for concepts and terms used in video game programming

Tags: android, model-view-controller, libgdx

I have been studying tutorials for `libgdx` for about a week now, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the various concepts, such as textures, vectors and matrices. Unfortunately, all of the tutorials I've read assume that you have a background in game programming.

I've been poring over the documentation and trying hard to make something of it, but at this point - I'd really love some suggestions for good books or online references that might help clarify some of the terminology. Google just isn't cutting it.

Any help?

Comment: Hmm, I learned about matrices in high school, and the rest seemed fairly easy after a bit of googling/wikpedia

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a book recommendation site, or a replacement for effort locating a search term that works in Google. Two of the three "concepts" you've mentioned (vectors and matrices) are high school math topics. Try a search on `matrices math` or `vectors math`. "Textures" should be available via Google easily as well (`textures graphics computer` might be a term to start with, for instance). Questions here should be specific, not vague "teach me how" or "help me find". We're really happy to try and help, but you have to do some basic work yourself first. :-)

Comment: Sorry for a bad question. I was just hoping if there is a compilation of all the terms/concepts I guess i should search them one by one for every term i see. thanks for the reply though

Comment: @WillingLearner Maybe posting here would be more appropriate towards your question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android+libgdx